# How to refer to an object definition in a UnitTesting DataSource in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I am writing unit tests using the Microsoft UnitTesting suite (`Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;`). With this, I have created an object to be used as a data source:

```
private static readonly object[] ValidLogRangesIntSource =
{
    new object[] { 1, 2, 1, new List<int> {1} } ,
    new object[] { int.MaxValue, 1, 1, new List<int> {int.MaxValue} } ,
    new object[] { int.MaxValue, 1, 2, new List<int> {int.MaxValue, 1} } ,
    new object[] { 1, 1000, 10,
        new List<int> { 1, 2, 5, 10, 22, 46, 100, 215, 464, 1000} },
    new object[] { 1000, 1, 10,
        new List<int> { 1, 2, 5, 10, 22, 46, 100, 215, 464, 1000} }
};
```

And I am trying to refer to these in my unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
[DataSource("ValidLogRangesIntSource")]
public void TestLogRangeWithValidIntValues(int start, int end, int steps, List<int> result)
{
    // MathUtil.LogRange(start, end, steps).Should().BeEquivalentTo(result);
    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(result, MathUtil.LogRange(start, end, steps));
}
```

However, when run, I get the error message

> Data source 'ValidLogRangesIntSource' cannot be found in the test configuration settings.

When investigating, the [documentation for DataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datasourceattribute.-ctor?view=mstest-net-1.2.0#Microsoft_VisualStudio_TestTools_UnitTesting_DataSourceAttribute__ctor_System_String_) informs the name should be in `app.config`; however I don't have this file.

Additionally, in NUnit, the data source worked well with `[TestCaseSource("ValidLogRangesIntSource")]` - I am looking for the same implementation.